# How can I repair my Android Studio IDE? (Error 23,24 ; Error 26,13 , missing classes and render problems)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have downloaded Android Studio and it has been since then giving me problems. I've reinstalled it 3 times and I've looked up those problems but I just can't find a solution!

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

It seems like I can't get passed the 2 errors shown below (23,24 ; 26,13). Note that if I click on "Install repository and sync project", it won't work.
Also my design window looks bad as I have render problems and missing classes.

Comment: Can you add your build.gradle file? That will help us solve the problem

Comment: ok I posted it in the answers section.

Comment: have you tried also deleting all the files in the Windows registry before reinstalling it, as well as the files/folders it puts on your C:/ drive that don't disappear after uninstall? I found that for me, that did the trick when I deleted and then reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the toolsets required for Gradle to sync your project. You need to install those appcompat and espresso libraries. You said the "Install repository and sync project" button "won't work", but can you clarify what that means? What exactly happens when you click that button?

It might help to share your build.gradle file.

Comment: Well it basically doesnt work. I click on that highlighted text and nothing happens.

Comment: Try this:

1) Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> "SDK Tools" Tab -> Expand "Support Repository" -> Check "Android Support Repository" -> OK

Comment: Have you tried just doing a clean build? 

1) Build -> Clean Project
2) Build -> Make Project

Comment: When I try to clean the project , this shows up:
https://imgur.com/a/UYSvw

Comment: And I posted my build.gradle file below ,by the way,

Answer (score 0):

Here is my build.gridle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.black.prima"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,  I tried a lot of these suggestions. I tried tried re-installing over and over and tried to delete all the files left over,  I have my account on my windows computer and a guest account set up on my computer so I tried a fresh install on the guest account and noticed also that I downloaded from was not the official site so I made sure I downloaded it from the official site and the new studio came up with no errors